# UpdateView django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hola quisiera saber si puedo paginar un UpdateView de django como lo puedo realizar tengo el siguiente codigo pero no se como puedo paginarlo

```
class RoutingForAniGroupUpdate(UpdateView):

    model = RoutingForAniGroup
    template_name = 'forms.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('routing:ani')
    success_message = "%(name)s was created successfully"
    form_class = RoutingForAniGroupForm
    object = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        # Formset
        formset = modelformset_factory(RoutingForAni, form=RoutingForAniForm, can_delete=True, extra=4)

        # formset.form = staticmethod(curry(RoutingForAniForm, user=self.request.user))
        query = self.object.routingforani_set.filter().order_by("id")[0:1]

        print("\n*****************\n**************\n",query.count())

        eventdate_formset = formset(queryset=query)
        #print(eventdate_formset)
        print(self.get_context_data)

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form, eventdate_formset=eventdate_formset)
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        # Formset
        formset = modelformset_factory(RoutingForAni, form=RoutingForAniForm, can_delete=True, extra=4)
        # formset.form = staticmethod(curry(RoutingForAniForm, user=self.request.user))
        eventdate_formset = formset(
            self.request.POST,
            queryset=self.object.routingforani_set.all()
        )

        if form.is_valid() and eventdate_formset.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, eventdate_formset)
        return self.form_invalid(form, eventdate_formset)

    def form_invalid(self, form, eventdate_formset):
        messages.error(self.request, "Invalid form data")
#        print(form, eventdate_formset)
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form, eventdate_formset=eventdate_formset)
        )

    def form_valid(self, form, eventdate_formset):
        response = super(RoutingForAniGroupUpdate, self).form_valid(form)
        instances = eventdate_formset.save(commit=False)

        for obj in eventdate_formset.deleted_objects:
            obj.delete()

        for obj in instances:
            obj.group_id = self.object.pk
            obj.save()

        messages.success(self.request, "Update ")
        return response
```

Comment: Lo que quieres es paginar el modelo relativo al modelo de la vista? Es decir, paginar los formsets?

Comment: Si paginar el formulario para editar solo lo paginado

Comment: Pero es tan sencillo como cortar el query que le envias al formset de acuerdo a la paginacion que quieras aplicar

Comment: no amigo pues me esta generando un error " 'Page' object has no attribute 'ordered' " esto es de la paginacion  paginacion

Comment: bueno el hecho es que por fin lo logre ;) ahora publico como lo he realizado gracias a todos por el aporte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que realize fue :

1. cambiar la formana del return de **render_to_response** a un **render**
2. lo que valida el metodo **formset** es un objeto de tipo lista y que este ordenado, asi que lo que se realizo fue paginar y luego lo que estaba paginado convertirlo con un **object_list**
3. adjunto la funcion get que fue la que modifique de la clase

   ```
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

   self.object = self.get_object()
   form_class = self.get_form_class()
   form = self.get_form(form_class)

   # Formset
   formset = modelformset_factory(RoutingForAni, form=RoutingForAniForm, can_delete=True, extra=4)
   # formset.form = staticmethod(curry(RoutingForAniForm, user=self.request.user))
   query = self.object.routingforani_set.filter().order_by('id')
   query = Paginator(query, 10)

   eventdate_formset = formset(queryset=query.page(1).object_list)

   return render(
       request,
       self.template_name,
       {   'form':form,
           'eventdate_formset':eventdate_formset,
           'objects':query

       }
   )
   ```

De esta manera es como logro resolver lo de la paginación en mi UpdateView siendo paginado con un tamaño de 10 Dies y ubicandome en la pagina 1 Uno 
gracias a todos por el aporte